# Is there a way to make my bot ignore everything untill wait_for() requirements is completed?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using `wait_for()` in my `on_message(message)` function, where it stops the spam and other functionalities if captcha is detected.

It waits for message sent by me : `completed` after the captcha detected but other commands still keeps working. I need all the functionality to be stopped until I send `completed` in chat manually.

here is a glimpse of the code:

```py
    @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ping = client.get_user(int(ping_id))
    channel = client.get_channel(int(catch_id))
    if message.channel.id == int(catch_id):
        if message.author.id == Abot:
            if message.embeds:
                embed_title = message.embeds[0].title
                if 'animal in wild has appeared!' in embed_title:
                    spam.cancel()
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    await channel.send('.hint')           
            else:
                content = message.content
                if 'The animal is ' in content:
                    if not len(solve(content)):
                        print('animal not found.')
                    else:
                        for i in solve(content):
                            await asyncio.sleep(1)
                            await channel.send(f'.catch {i}')
                    check = random.randint(1, 60)
                    if check == 1:
                      await asyncio.sleep(900)
                      spam.start()
                    else:
                      await asyncio.sleep(1)
                      spam.start()

                elif 'Congratulations' in content:
                    global rare1
                    global rare2
                    global num_animal
                    global rare3
                    num_animal += 1
                    split = content.split(' ')
                    animal = split[7].replace('!','')
                    if 'unusual...' in content:
                        rare1 += 1
                        print(f'rare1 animal caught! animal: {animal}')
                        print(f'rare1: {rare1} | rare2: {rare2} | rare3: {rare3}')
                    elif re.findall('^'+animal+'$', rare1_list, re.MULTILINE):
                        rare1 += 1
                        print(f'rare1 animal caught! Animal: {animal}')
                        print(f'rare1: {rare1}')
                    elif re.findall('^'+animal+'$', rare3_list, re.MULTILINE):
                        rare3 += 1
                        print(f'rare3 animal caught! animal: {rare3}')
                        print(f'rare3: {rare3}')
                    else:
                        print(f'Total Animal Caught: {num_animal}')
                elif 'whoa!' in content:
                  spam.cancel()
                  msg_id = message.id
                  id = message.guild.id
                  await channel.send('Captcha Detected <@868169393866178570>')
                  await ping.send('Hello <@804967354970669057> Captcha detected')
                  log = client.get_channel(int(log_id))
                  await log.send('https://discord.com/channels/' + str(id) + '/' + str(catch_id) + '/' + str(msg_id))
                  print('Captcha detected')
                  def check(m):
                        return m.content == 'completed' and m.channel == channel and m.author.id == owner_id
                  cap = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
                  await channel.send('.hint'.format(cap))
                  spam.start()
    if not message.author.bot:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

I want it to stop its all functionality untill I say `completed` after it detects captcha.

If it possible then help please.

Comment: You can set a flag before waiting then check if the flag is set before running a different command

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit like how ? because  i am not so good in these stuffs and technical terms.

Comment: You can, for example, add the user's id into something (probably set) and then check/update it at the beginning of any handlers you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a global variable e.g. `waiting_for_completion = False`. Whenever a new message is detected, you only process it if "waiting_for_completion" is False. Then, when a captcha is detected, you set `waiting_for_completion = True`. You set it back to False when you receive the "completed" message.

Example:

```
waiting_for_completion = False

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ping = client.get_user(int(ping_id))
    channel = client.get_channel(int(catch_id))
    global waiting_for_completion
    if message.channel.id == int(catch_id) and not waiting_for_completion:
        if message.author.id == Abot:
            if message.embeds:
                embed_title = message.embeds[0].title
                if 'animal in wild has appeared!' in embed_title:
                    spam.cancel()
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    await channel.send('.hint')           
            else:
                content = message.content
                if 'The animal is ' in content:
                    if not len(solve(content)):
                        print('animal not found.')
                    else:
                        for i in solve(content):
                            await asyncio.sleep(1)
                            await channel.send(f'.catch {i}')
                    check = random.randint(1, 60)
                    if check == 1:
                      await asyncio.sleep(900)
                      spam.start()
                    else:
                      await asyncio.sleep(1)
                      spam.start()

                elif 'Congratulations' in content:
                    global rare1
                    global rare2
                    global num_animal
                    global rare3
                    num_animal += 1
                    split = content.split(' ')
                    animal = split[7].replace('!','')
                    if 'unusual...' in content:
                        rare1 += 1
                        print(f'rare1 animal caught! animal: {animal}')
                        print(f'rare1: {rare1} | rare2: {rare2} | rare3: {rare3}')
                    elif re.findall('^'+animal+'$', rare1_list, re.MULTILINE):
                        rare1 += 1
                        print(f'rare1 animal caught! Animal: {animal}')
                        print(f'rare1: {rare1}')
                    elif re.findall('^'+animal+'$', rare3_list, re.MULTILINE):
                        rare3 += 1
                        print(f'rare3 animal caught! animal: {rare3}')
                        print(f'rare3: {rare3}')
                else:
                    print(f'Total Animal Caught: {num_animal}')
            elif 'whoa!' in content:
              spam.cancel()
              msg_id = message.id
              id = message.guild.id
              await channel.send('Captcha Detected <@868169393866178570>')
              await ping.send('Hello <@804967354970669057> Captcha detected')
              log = client.get_channel(int(log_id))
              await log.send('https://discord.com/channels/' + str(id) + '/' + str(catch_id) + '/' + str(msg_id))
              print('Captcha detected')
              def check(m):
                    return m.content == 'completed' and m.channel == channel and m.author.id == owner_id
              waiting_for_completion = True
              cap = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
              waiting_for_completion = False
              await channel.send('.hint'.format(cap))
              spam.start()
if not message.author.bot:
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

If you have a lot of global variables, you might want to consider using OOP for your bot and storing the variables related to your bot as attributes.

Comment: Ty for your solution. Now commands are working while captcha is detected But now I can't use any of the command even when captcha hasn't arrived, It is giving me error everytime.                                              ```                                                                  ```File "main.py", line 128, in on_message                                                 cap = await client.wait_for('message', check=test)                                                    UnboundLocalError: Local variable 'check' referenced before assignment.```

Comment: sorry, the two lines `await client.wait_for('message', check=test)                                                    UnboundLocalError: Local variable 'check' referenced before assignment.` together don't seem to fit together. I this the exact output you got?

Comment: hello @Nik , it said error is in the line `File "main.py", line 128, in on_message                                                 cap = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)         `                                       and the error is ``UnboundLocalError: Local variable 'check' referenced before assignment``